How to get connectionId in react native using @microsoft/signalr
import { HubConnectionBuilder, HttpTransportType, HubConnection } from '@microsoft/signalr';

class SignalRManager {
    static _hubConnectionUser;

    static createConnection(email) {
        if (!globalThis.document) {
            globalThis.document = undefined;
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const connectionUrl = `https://url?user=${email}`;

            const _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(connectionUrl, {
                    skipNegotiation: true,
                    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
                })
                .build();

            _hubConnection.start()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Hub started', _hubConnection);


                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Hub failed', connectionUrl, err);
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }

    static stopConnection(onCompletion) {
        this.removeAllListeners();
        SignalRManager._hubConnectionUser?.stop().then(() => {
            console.log('Connection stopped successfully');
            onCompletion();
        }).catch(err => {
            onCompletion();
            console.log('Stop connection error', err);
        });
    }

    static removeAllListeners() {
        const _hubConnection = SignalRManager._hubConnectionUser;
        // Assuming SignalRUserServerEvents is an array or object of events
        Object.values(SignalRUserServerEvents).forEach(event => {
            _hubConnection.off(event);
        });
    }

    static registerUserEventListener(event, listener, ...params) {
        const eventName = stringFormat(event, params);
        console.log('registerUserEventListener', eventName);
        SignalRManager._hubConnectionUser.on(eventName, data => {
            console.log(`User SignalR:${eventName}`, data);
            listener(data);
        });
    }
}

export default SignalRManager;

  useEffect(() => {
        const connect = async () => {
            const connection = await SignalRManager.createConnection(`${data?.Email}`)
                .then(() => console.log('Connection established'))
                .catch(err => console.error('Connection failed', err));
            console.log('connection', connection);
        }
        connect();

    }, [data?.Email]);

The connection is established, but I need the connectionId to send a message. But I'm not getting the connectionId

Each client connecting to a hub passes a unique connection id. You can retrieve this value in the Context.ConnectionId property of the hub context if you want to get it in the Server Hub. And if you want to get it from the client, we might use console.info(_hubConnection) to find out the connection id property.

We don't have an official sample or document for react client + asp.net core server signalr, but the server Hubs are the same, so that at least we can create a Hub method like below and call it from the client in _hubConnection.start() which should be similar to _hubConnection.start().then(function(){connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function(connectionId){console.log(connectionId)})}).catch(err => console.error(err));
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
}

But the app is using the same @microsoft/signalr as the js client sample showed, so that I'm afraid we might try var connectionid = _hubConnection.connection.connectionId; after the connection had set up.
